# check if input is an empty array or empty array of arrays and save as just empty array otherwise copy the array of objects

Tags: json, jolt

check if input is an empty array or empty array of arrays and save as just empty array otherwise copy the array of objects.
Any help is appreciated

```json
{
  "response": {
    "body": {
      "variables": {
        "sample": {
          "type": "Json",
          "value": [
            [
              []
            ]
          ],
          "valueInfo": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "response": {
        "body": {
          "variables": {
            "sample": {
              "value": "."
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
 []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of wrappers(*square brackets*) of the array by successively using **split** and **join** functions within the **modify** transformation in order to measure whether the size of the remaining array is *zero* or *not*, and then determine the results depending on this result such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "response": {
        "body": {
          "variables": {
            "sample": {
              "str0": "=toString(@(1,value))",
              "str1": "@(1,str0[0])",
              "str2": "=split('\\[', @(1,str1))",
              "str3": "=join('',@(1,str2))",
              "str4": "=split('\\]', @(1,str3))",
              "sz": "=size(@(1,str4))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "response": {
        "body": {
          "variables": {
            "sample": {
              "sz": {
                "0": { "@(2,str4)": "" },
                "*": { "@(2,value)": "" }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Can we make sure we can have objects and does not have array inside array

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what exactly you mean @Sandy